# java; keep getting a java.lang.String when setting the text to a String

Tags: java, jframe

It's Java Starter here, so again in my Password Generation Program,
So, i tried to make a Option to Generate Multiple passwords with a space between them.

Example:
PASSWORD1

PASSWORD2

But when i set the "password" text to the textfield i keep getting stuff like this: ADWADjava.lang.StringQE_Q12

I didn't find any error in my code, or something that causes to the java.lang.String to pop up, If you know what's wrong please Reply to this question or Send an answer to it.

My Code:

```
    createPass.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                field.setText(null);
                field.setText("");
                String[] pass = new String[5];
                for(int i = 0; i < pass.length ; i++) {
                    pass[i] = allrandom();


                }
                for(int i = 0; i < pass.length ; i++) {
                    field.setText(field.getText() + pass[i]);
                }


            }});



}
    public static String allrandom() {
        String cpass = "";
        password = "";
        String[] pass = new String[15];
        Random r = new Random();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < pass.length ; i++) {
        int ch = 0;
        ch = r.nextInt(3);
        switch(ch) {
        case 0:
            if(passsettings.isIfDots()) {
                String newchar = ""; 
                newchar = dotpass();
                pass[i] = newchar;
                break;
            }
        case 1:
            if(passsettings.isIfNum()) {
                String newchar2 = ""; 
                newchar2 = Numpass();
                pass[i] = newchar2;
                break;
            }
        case 2:

            String newchar3 = ""; 
            newchar3 = charchose();
            pass[i] = newchar3;
            break;
        }

    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < pass.length ; i++) {
        String newpasschar = "";
        newpasschar = pass[i];
        cpass = pass + newpasschar;
    }
    cpass = cpass + "\n";
    return cpass;


        // random() end
    }


    public static String uppercasepass() {
        String[] abc = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
        Random r = new Random();
        String passletter = "";
        int rN3 = 0;
        rN3 = r.nextInt(26);
        passletter = abc[rN3];



        return passletter;
    // uppercase() end
}

    public static String lowercasepass() {
        Random r = new Random();
        String passletter = "";
        int rN3 = 0;
        rN3 = r.nextInt(26);
        String[] abc = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
        passletter = abc[rN3];
        return passletter;
    }

    public static String Numpass() {
        Random r = new Random();
        String passletter = "";
        int rN = 0;
        rN = r.nextInt(9);
        String[] nums = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
        passletter = nums[rN];
        return passletter;
    }

    public static String dotpass() {
        Random r = new Random();
        String passletter = "";
        int rN5 = 0;
        rN5 = r.nextInt(6);
        String[] dots = {"_","]","$","#","=","@"};
        passletter = dots[rN5];




        return passletter;
    }


    public static String charchose() {
        Random r = new Random();
        String line = "";
        int rN = 0;
        rN = r.nextInt(2);
        String[] random = {"Low","Up"};
        String random2 = random[rN];
        switch(random2) {
        case "Low":
            if(passsettings.isIfLowercase()) {
                line = lowercasepass();
            }else {
                charchose();
            }
        case "Up":
            if(passsettings.isIfUpprcase()) {
                line = uppercasepass();
            }else {
                charchose();
            }
        }










        return line;
    }
```

Thanks,

- Java Starter

Comment: NOTE: i did try it with System.out.println and everything was working correcly.

Comment: `field.getText().toString()`

Comment: @JavaStarter Precise this. If you tested (with the use of a sysout for example) some methods, you should see where the error comes from. In your case, this is at the `setText` right?

Comment: Its looks like your getting text from the toString() method instead from the getText() method?

Comment: Please reduce this to a well-formatted [mcve]. Currently the code is long (148 lines), incomplete, and poorly formatted. Please bear in mind that Stack Overflow aims to be a repository of high-quality questions. It can take a very long time to write a [really good question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) but I promise you, it's worth the effort.

Comment: @MinhKieu No im using the getText() method.

Comment: I´m with Jon Skeet on that one. Try to reduce the amount of code to the neccessary parts so we can give a high quality answer. However I would highly recommend to have also have a look at the java documentation about the usage of JTextField and JPasswordField. You might even find the error by yourself that way

Comment: how did you get the output above? I see no System.out.println()? If your seeing it in the debugger than perhaps the tool is using JTextField.toString().

Comment: `cpass = pass + newpasschar;` is an issue, as `pass` is a `String[]`, which means you're trying to concatenate a `String[]` and another `String`, which results in an unwanted conversation to `[Ljava.lang.String`, in fact, just making it `cpass += newpasschar;` seems to solve the core issue

Comment: Also, please, please, PLEASE, learn how to use `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 1):

When debugging your code, I had issue with (a lot of things, but mainly)...

```
public static String allrandom() {
    String cpass = "";
    password = "";
    String[] pass = new String[15];
    //...
    for (int i = 0; i < pass.length; i++) {
        String newpasschar = "";
        newpasschar = pass[i];
        cpass = pass + newpasschar;
    }
    cpass = cpass + "\n";
    return cpass;

    // random() end
}
```

`pass + newpasschar` is trying to concatenate an array and a `String` object.  This is basically the same as doing `pass.toString() + newpasschar.toString()`

Why you're doing this, I don't know as `cpass += newpasschar` would have achieved the result you are looking for.

I really don't want to go through all you could and point all your issues, but let's say...Learn how to use `StringBuilder` - it's way more efficient

The whole thing just screams custom class to me, particularly using a builder pattern, for example...

```
public class PasswordBuilder {

    private List<String> characters;
    private List<String> numbers;
    private List<String> dots;

    private boolean useDots = true;
    private boolean useNumbers = true;
    private boolean useLowerCase = true;
    private boolean useUpperCase = true;

    private int length;

    public PasswordBuilder(int length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

    public PasswordBuilder useDots(boolean use) {
        useDots = use;
        return this;
    }

    public PasswordBuilder useNumbers(boolean use) {
        useNumbers = use;
        return this;
    }

    public PasswordBuilder userLowerCase(boolean use) {
        useLowerCase = use;
        return this;
    }

    public PasswordBuilder useUpperCase(boolean use) {
        useUpperCase = use;
        return this;
    }

    protected int getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    protected boolean isUsingDots() {
        return useDots;
    }

    protected boolean isUsingNumbers() {
        return useNumbers;
    }

    protected boolean isUsingLowerCase() {
        return useLowerCase;
    }

    protected boolean isUsingUpperCase() {
        return useUpperCase;
    }

    public String build() {
        characters = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"));
        numbers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"));
        dots = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("_", "]", "$", "#", "=", "@"));

        Random r = new Random();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(getLength());
        for (int i = 0; sb.length() < getLength(); i++) {
            switch (r.nextInt(3)) {
                case 0:
                    if (isUsingDots()) {
                        sb.append(dotpass());
                        break;
                    }
                case 1:
                    if (isUsingNumbers()) {
                        sb.append(Numpass());
                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    sb.append(charchose());
                    break;
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    protected String randomFrom(List<String> values) {
        Collections.shuffle(values);
        return values.get(0);
    }

    protected String uppercasepass() {
        return randomFrom(characters).toLowerCase();
    }

    protected String lowercasepass() {
        return randomFrom(characters).toLowerCase();
    }

    protected String Numpass() {
        return randomFrom(numbers);
    }

    public String dotpass() {
        return randomFrom(dots);
    }

    protected String charchose() {
        Random r = new Random();
        int value = r.nextInt(2);
        String text = "";
        switch (value) {
            case 0:
                text = lowercasepass();
            case 1:
                text = uppercasepass();
        }
        return text;
    }

}
```

Which means you can simply do something like...

```
System.out.println(new PasswordBuilder(15).build());
System.out.println(new PasswordBuilder(15).useNumbers(false).build());
System.out.println(new PasswordBuilder(15).userLowerCase(false).build());
System.out.println(new PasswordBuilder(15).userLowerCase(false).useUpperCase(false).build());
```

and have it output something like...

```
xt7$93l]]#]@$xc
]o#r=#pxhk@lyth
@_s5q6]#8i$h]##
2#ccw_1]m3kaz_1
```

There are a number of points in your code where you could end up with a recursive (stack) overflow, where you call a method over and over again, so you really need to check the state of the available flags and make sure that at least one is `true`

You could still use arrays (instead of `List`s), but the basic idea remains the same

Comment: I may use your password builder, But i really feel stupid now not noticing that "error" with the pass + newpasschar error...